# v8 callback not working with JavaScript objects on the heap

Tags: javascript, c++, callback, node.js-addon

I create an instance of a JavaScript object, like;

```
myObj1 = new myObject("Object1");
```

I then call a node.js c++ addon, which does a callback to the Javascript object...

```
myAddon = require('myAddon');
myAddon.greet(myObj1.name);
```

The c++ callback code looks like:

```
Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]);
Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();
const int argc = 1;
const char *parm = "Hello";
v8::Local<v8::Value> argv[argc] = {  v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, parm) };
callback->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

But the problem is that the binding doesn't callback to the instance of the myObject, rather it appears to callback to the base JavaScript class. So there is no instance data.

From what I have been able to read over the past 2 days, the first parameter to the Call() method somehow becomes the "this" pointer in v8. So I would guess the problem might be that I am using a Global context

Does anyone have a clue how to correctly callback to a JavaScript object on the heap?

Comment: Can you confirm these details: (1) the C++ code is the native implementation of `myAddon.greet()`, and (2) you are attempting to access the object `myObj1` from this C++ code? If that is the case, then is `myObj1.name` a function?

Comment: @cdhowie - Yes indeed, the C++ code is the native implementation of myAddon.greet(), and I pass in myObj1.name, intending this to be the address of the name function in the instance. I also tried passing in the entire object , and using the C++ code to extract the method from the object, but same result. It's driving me nuts.

Comment: In the example you have given, *you cannot obtain `myObj1` in your C++ code.* The correct way to do this would be to bind `this` from the JavaScript side: `myAddon.greet(myObj1.name.bind(myObj1));`, just as you must do for every other kind of callback. Then you simply don't care about it on the C++ side.

Comment: @cdhowie, many thanks for helping, I am still learning all of this, and I haven't come across the bind() stuff. I will go read up on it. If you want to change your comment to an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @cdhowie Works like a charm. I guess I have some JavaScript learning to do. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` value is only set when you *invoke* a method in the form `a.b(...)` or `a[c](...)` where `a` is any expression and `b` is an attribute name (or `c` is an expression evaluating as an attribute name) and the attribute value is a function.

That's a lot to unpack, but basically what it means is that when you do `a.b.c(d)` then the function stored at `a.b.c` is invoked with the value of the expression `a.b` being bound to `this` in that function's context.

That is *the only time* this kind of magic happens.

So, when you invoke `myAddon.greet(myObj1.name)`, the function `greet` (fetched from the object `myAddon`) is invoked with `this` being set to `myAddon`.  There is no other magic happening.  In particular, `myObj1.name` is evaluated, found to be a function, and this function object is passed as an argument.  *The detail that the function was obtained from `myObj1` is not retained,* which means that your C++ code as no mechanism it can use to obtain a reference to this object!

Instead, the proper way to do this in JavaScript is for the code passing the callback to bind `this` as it needs, using the [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) method of functions, like so:

```
myAddon.greet(myObj1.name.bind(myObj1));
```

Your C++ code will receive a proxy function object (`bind()` creates a new function).  This proxy will invoke the `myObj1.name` function with `this` being set to `myObj1`, so your C++ code simply doesn't have to care about it.

To illustrate, the expression `myObj1.name.bind(myObj1)` is roughly equivalent to

```
(function (o, f) {
    return function () { return f.apply(o, arguments); };
}(myObj1, myObj1.name))
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to educate - a great answer.

Comment: at the risk of being really cheeky - my real life JavaScript object has 5 methods that I will want to call from C++. Do I need to pass 5 bound functions, or is there away to pass a bound object?

Comment: @Greycon I mean, you can just pass `myObj1` directly. You would just have to document the structure this object is expected to have so that other developers passing in objects can make sure they are passing you something you can use.

Comment: I originally did pass myObj1 directly , then used the C++ v8 api to extract the 5 methods from the object and called them as needed , but that's when I first encountered the "this" problem .

Comment: Essentially the JavaScript object needs to supply 5 Lifecycle methods which I want a C++ addon to manage and call. Im thinking of making a single bound function now, which I will pass to the C++ addon, and this function can act as a facade for all 5 functions when called by the addon

Comment: @Greycon You'd just have to pass the `Local<Object>` or `Persistent<Object>` representing `myObj1` as the first parameter to `Call()`.  .. Right?

Comment: That is the very rabbit hole I spend all of today working on . I simply couldn't get the v8::Function::call to accept anything other than the GlobalContext as a first parameter. I did not try passing persistent<Object>  Am on my third beer now (working in Germany) so will give it a go first thing tomorrow. If you ever get to Ireland, the drinks are on me

Comment: @Greycon There's two overloads, I think... one takes an execution context (v8 environment) and a thisarg + arguments, the other only takes a thisarg + arguments.

Comment: final solution now working, it was your comment about passing a thisarg to Function::Call that did it for me. Many thanks again.